# Extracting a word from a sentence in a variable

Tags: grep

I have a variable containing the following value: `|| InstanceId | i-0f85cb9ccb11fd035 ||`

The variable is dynamically generated and I need to extract the InstanceId value from this variable.

The instance Id will always begin with `I-` or found between the single and double pipe.

Trying to use grep on a MacOS bash script to do so.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: This is the job of regular expressions. What have you tried?

Comment: Id use cut - echo $varname | cut -f3 -d'|'

Answer (score 2):

To replace a string, you'd need to use `sed`. Here's how to do it.

```
$ var="|| InstanceId | i-0f85cb9ccb11fd035 ||"
$ printf '%s\n' "$var" | sed -r 's/\|\|[^\|]+\| [iI]-([^ ]+) \|\|/\1/g'
```

`'s/\|\|[^\|]+\| [iI]-([^ ]+) \|\|/\1/g'` is the pattern you'd need to understand.

`s/something/replacement/g` means replace any occurances of 'something' with 'replacement'.

`\|` is just an escaped pipe character.

So we're looking for two pipes, followed by `[^\|]+`, ie, a sequence of one or more non-pipe characters. This is followed by another pipe and a space, `\|`. Then we match either `i-` or `I-`, read a sequence of non-space characters, put them in a group by using parenthesis, `([^ ]+)` and followed by space and two pipes `\|\|`.

Then we replace this whole thing by the first group, that is `\1`.